# How to view html content in a new window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, attachment

I want an html attachment to be opened in a new window and view the content, but its not working. Below is the code which I have implemented:-

```
window.open( "data:text/html" + encodeURIComponent(response));
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing a comma there:

```
window.open( "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(response)); 
                            ^
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kZnY/1/)

The Data URI syntax is:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/data_URIs)

---

As a side note, if you want to open an actual pop-up window instead of a new tab, pass a small `width` and `height` in the 3rd parameter of [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open). Behavior may vary between browsers.

To avoid issues with popup blockers and some cross-browser inconsistencies, you can use one of the many dialog/modal plugins available. HTML5's `<dialog>` element with [dialog-polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill) is suitable for most use cases.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You sure? I've tested in Chrome and Firefox. What OS?

Comment: It opens a new tab with the proper rendered HTML on my Chrome 34 / Windows. @RobertHarvey could you be a bit more specific with "doesn't work", please? Does it show garbled data, error in the console, gets blocked by popup blocker?

Comment: Well, it only works if I completely disable my popup blocker (whitelisting doesn't seem to work).

Comment: @RobertHarvey seems weird, I've updated the fiddle to respond to a button click, this way it doesn't get blocked by Chrome nor Firefox's default popup blockers. Are you using any other popup blocker besides the browser's built-in one?

Comment: Better Popup blocker.  The test image they have on [their page](http://optimalcycling.com/other-projects/better-pop-up-blocker/) works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah I see. You probably can't whitelist the popup domain because it has no domain (it is a data URI), report a bug/issue to them. `=]`